# Do all Katsura trees (Cercidiphyllum japonicum) have seeds/pods?

Tags: trees, seeds

I'm trying to figure out if male Katsura trees ([*Cercidiphyllum japonicum*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cercidiphyllum_japonicum)) are "cleaner" in terms of the seeds/pods they shed in the yard versus the females.

Do all Katsura trees have seeds/pods? Or is it just the females that have seeds/pods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both male and female Katsura trees flower, but, as is the way of life generally, only the females produce seed pods (if their flowers have been pollinated).